# Problems getting correct data using a date range in flutter and firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have run into a problem I can't understand. I have a record (document) in my firestore cloud with a date og type Timestamp

[image: doc definition]

[image: date is of type Timestamp]

I have made a Stream where I get the records (document) depending on ion they are within a specie week. First time it finds data that match a certain date range it doesn't find data if I change to another date range but always return the first one.  I have included code and some debug info. Is there some cache functionality I need to refresh or am I doing it wrongly

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

stream: DatabaseService().getRegistrationsByDateRange(firstDayOfWeek, lastDayOfWeek),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return const Center(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Something went wrong'),
      ),
    );
  }
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    Map<String, Registration> regMap = {};
    for (var object in snapshot.data!.docs) {
      Registration result = Registration.fromQueryDocumentSnapshot(object);
      regMap[object.reference.id] = result;
    }
    regMap.removeWhere((key, value) => filterOnRegistrationDate(value));
    if (regMap.isNotEmpty) {
      categoriseRegistration(regMap);
    }
  }

 void categoriseRegistration(Map<String, Registration> regMap) {
    Map<String, Map<DateTime, RegistrationUnit>> gridList = {};
    regMap.forEach((docID, registrationObject) {
      Map<DateTime, RegistrationUnit>? tempHolder = {};
      RegistrationUnit ru = RegistrationUnit(
          docID: docID,
          projectID: registrationObject.projectID,
          description: TextEditingController(text: registrationObject.descriptionText),
          hours: TextEditingController(text: registrationObject.registrationTime.toString()),
          registrationDate: DateTime.parse(registrationObject.registrationDate.toDate().toString()));
      if (gridList.containsKey(registrationObject.projectID)) {
        tempHolder = Map.of(gridList[registrationObject.projectID]!);
      }
      String dt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(registrationObject.registrationDate.toDate().toString())).toString();
      tempHolder[DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(dt)] = ru;
      gridList[registrationObject.projectID] = tempHolder;
    });
    registrationListDB = gridList;
  }

// From DatabaseSerive()
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getRegistrationsByDateRange(DateTime firstDayOfWeek, DateTime lastDayOfWeek) {
    Timestamp ts1, ts2;
    ts1 = Timestamp.fromDate(firstDayOfWeek);
    ts2 = Timestamp.fromDate(lastDayOfWeek);
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Registration')
        .where('registrationDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: ts1)
        .where('registrationDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: ts2)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Data first time I read from database

[image: Date range I search for first time]
[image: Data first time I get a match]

Data I getting next date Range

[image: Date range i'm searching within]
[image: Data I receive]

I would expect that I get data where registrationDate is within the date range I specify in my firstDayOfWeek and lastDayOfWeek but that does really happen. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you didn't call `setState` to rebuild `StreamBuilder` after you change `firstDayOfWeek, lastDayOfWeek`.